# How do I profile React Native (Expo) for memory leaks?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native

I have an iOS react native app.

When I run `Instruments` it just shows memory increasing over time / the address / the size. Which is really difficult to work with because there are many components being rendered. I can't figure out which ones are leaking memory.

Is there a way to tell for sure which components are leaking memory?

Or maybe the Android emulator is better?

Or maybe even running it straight from my phone is better?

Please advise me.

Comment: Ever found an answer?